# In the for loop, the constant variable will be declared as many time as the loop runs. Why its not an error?

Tags: javascript, web-deployment

```js
for(let i =0; i<10;i++){
    const a = i;               
    console.log(a);
}

const b = 5;
const b = 10;   

for(const i =0; i<10;i++){
    const a = i;                
    console.log(a);
} 

enter code here
```

In above code b is declared twice so system is giving an error. **Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'b' has already been declared**

In the for loop, the constant variable will be declared as many time as the loop runs. Why its not an error?

In the second loop why the const i throwing an error? Is const i in the for loop initialisation have a different scope?

Comment: Because in the loop the variable is not created twice in the same scope, `const` can be declared in a block scope, and each round of the `for` loop creates its own scope.

Comment: Each loop *iteration* has its own scope. (And `for` plays a bit of a clever game copying the `i` from the previous scope to the `i` for the new one just before doing the update expression.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If that's the case then why  this throws an error?  ----->                 for(const i =0; i<10;i++){

}